# In Extjs store can we query with 2 columns and 2 values?

Tags: extjs, store

I am using extjs(3.6) store.

In that we can query with single column and a value, I need to query with multiple columns and multiple values.

Please suggest any methods available in extjs?

Thanks in advance,

Ramanavel Selvaraj

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use queryBy method

```
store.queryBy(function(record,id){
     return (record.get('oneField') == someValue && record.get('secondField') == otherValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use queryBy method. I hope This answer will help you.

```
  getStaffName: function(staffId, departmentId){

    var staff= store.queryBy(function(record){
        return (record.get('staffId') == staffId && record.get('departmentId') == departmentId);
    });

    if (staff.getCount() > 0) {
        try {
            return staff.items[0].data.staffName;
        }catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return "Undefined";
        }

    }
    return "Undefined";
}
```